# Where to buy bicycle quality custom playing cards

Tags: playing-cards

I have the ideas (and graphics) for two decks of cards. Googling I only found two options for creating custom playing cards in the bicycle quality/style that seemed legit.

One: custom decks from the [official bicycle website](http://www.bicyclecards.com/custom-playing-cards). Looks good to begin with, but I called the number for more info, and discovered that bicycle can not make only 1 or 2 decks.

Two: [Zazzle](http://www.zazzle.com/custom/playingcards) makes playing cards! Again looks good to begin with, but after starting the process it quickly became apparent that zazzle only allows customization of the back. I need more than that.

The first deck will need custom backs, jokers, royals, and tuck case. The second will need custom backs, all faces, and tuck case.

So, anyone know of another legit company?

Note: I am a amateur magician, and for the cards to be of use they *must* have the feel of bicycle cards.

Comment: Not a direct answer, but: on [Kickstarter](http://www.kickstarter.com/) there are literally dozens of projects for custom decks many of them use Bicycle cards (Here a random one: http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/619318741/e8-garden-deck-bicycle-playing-cards?ref=live). You could try contacting the creators and ask where they have them made.

Answer (score 1):

There are several that do small print runs. (I am sure there are many more.)But, for Bicycle quality cards, you would likely need to use Bicycle as your source.

- [ArtsCow](http://www.artscow.com/photo-gifts/playing-cards/playing-cards-54-designs-313)
- [Printstudio](http://www.printerstudio.com/unique-ideas/custom-playing-cards.html)
- [theGameCrafter](http://www.thegamecrafter.com/)
- [QPC](http://www.customizedplayingcards.com/)

Comment: Have you seen the product of these sites yourself? I need the deck to have the quality and feel of a bicycle deck, unlike the cheap decks promotional and games often use.

Comment: +1 for Artscow. Though I can't vouch for the quality personally, I understand they're pretty good. May be worth a try at least.

Comment: I cannot vouch for the quality of any of these companies.

Answer (score 1):

You could also check out [Customized Playing Cards](http://customizedplayingcards.com/) I had them make me a custom card game that came out amazingly. The paper quality they used was 310 GSM which is what bicycle playing cards uses. Honestly the customer service alone will make me be a repeat customer. There was a small hiccup in the very beginning but it was quickly resolved.